# Tabular and longtable won't span over multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable

I am trying to get the following table to span over multiple pages or columns. I have tried using longtable instead of table but that ends up causing other issues. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering\captionsetup{justification = centering}
\begin{tabular}{|c c c c c c|} 
    \hline
    \#Nodes & Partition Type & Time & Cut & Energy & Modularity \\ [0.5ex] 
    \hline\hline
    
    \multirow{8}{*}{9} & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 473.26 $\mu$s & -11 & 17 & 0.170 \\
     & girvan-newman \rowcolor{yellow} & 2.01 ms & -7 & 20 & 0.180 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal cut & 46.04 ms & -11 & 19 & 0.186 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal energy & 46.04 ms & -7 & 20 & 0.180 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal modularity & 46.04 ms & -11 & 19 & 0.186 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 1.46 ns & -7 & 15 & 0.125 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 1.46 ns & -11 & 16 & 0.186 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 1.46 ns & -11 & 17 & 0.170 \\  \hline
   
    \multirow{8}{*}{18} & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 715.02 $\mu$s & -60 & 83 & 0.284 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan-newman & 29.86 ms & -64 & 89 & 0.306 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal cut & 72.48 s & -64 & 89 & 0.305 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal energy & 72.48 s & 32 & 101 & 0.149 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal modularity & 72.48 s & -64 & 89 & 0.305 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 5.83 ns & -32 & 67 & 0.245 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 5.83 ns & -32 & 73 & 0.183 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 5.83 ns & -36 & 73 & 0.208 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#3 & 5.83 ns & -44 & 74 & 0.247 \\ \hline
   
    \multirow{5}{*}{20} & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 979.42 $\mu$s & -74 & 85 & 0.203 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan-newman & 44.43 ms & -82 & 85 & 0.224 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 7.20 ns & -42 & 67 & 0.170 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 7.20 ns & -46 & 70 & 0.160 \\ 
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 7.20 ns & -58 & 74 & 0.184 \\ \hline
     
    \multirow{9}{*}{22} & \rowcolor{yellow} metis & 1.64 ms & -92 & 91 & 0.177 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 1.61 ms & -92 & 89 & 0.177 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan-newman & 84.34 ms & 180 & 101 & -0.00296 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal cut & 2.09 ks & -92 & 93 & 0.178 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal energy & 2.09 ks & -36 & 101 & 0.124 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal modularity & 2.09 ks & -92 & 93 & 0.178 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 8.71 ns & -76 & 81 & 0.152, \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 8.71 ns & -76 & 81 & 0.152 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 8.71 ns & -88 & 88 & 0.169 \\ \hline
  
    \multirow{8}{*}{24} & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 1.32 ms & -104 & 108 & 0.173 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan_newman & 156.77 ms & -104 & 104 & 0.178 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal cut & 8.58 ks & -108 & 108 & 0.18 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal energy & 8.58 ks & -44 & 126 & 0.133 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal modularity & 8.58 ks & -108 & 108 & 0.18 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 10.37 ns & -96 & 100 & 0.166 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 10.37 ns & -96 & 100 & 0.166 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 10.37 ns & -100 & 103 & 0.172 \\ \hline


    \multirow{9}{*}{24} & \rowcolor{yellow} metis & 1.36 ms  & -120 & 153 & 0.306  \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 15.03 ms & -120 & 153 & 0.306 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan-newman & 113.37 ms & -104 & 142 & 0.272  \\ 
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal cut & 11.05 ks & -120 & 150 & 0.306  \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal energy & 11.05 ks & 76 & 178 & 0.125  \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal modularity & 11.05 ks & -120 & 150 & 0.306  \\ 
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 1.44 ns & -84 & 160 & 0.234 \\ 
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 1.44 ns & -104 & 163 & 0.287  \\ 
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 1.44 ns & -116 & 157 & 0.3  \\ \hline 
  
    \multirow{10}{*}{25} & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 56.65 ms & -131 & 121 & 0.202 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan-newman & 547.38 ms & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal cut & 19.97 ks & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal energy & 19.97 ks & -59 & 138 & 0.147 \\
     & \rowcolor{cyan} ideal modularity & 19.97 ks & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 11.25 ns & -103 & 106 & 0.177 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#3 & 11.25 ns & -87 & 103 & 0.155 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#4 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\ \hline 
  
    \multirow{6}{*}{35} & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 1.66 ms & -233 & 324 & 0.294 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan-newman & 584.88 ms & -185 & 364 & 0.274 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 22.05 ns & -157 & 269 & 0.269 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 22.05 ns & -93 & 251 & 0.218 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 22.05 ns & -117 & 252 & 0.255 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#3 & 22.05 ns & -105 & 250 & 0.241 \\ \hline
    
    \multirow{5}{*}{50} & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 2.02 ms & -356 & 770 & 0.348 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan-newman & 776.80 ms & -8 & 556 & 0.269 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 45.00 ns & 92 & 522 & 0.240 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 45.00 ns & 108 & 520 & 0.225 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#2 & 45.00 ns & 68 & 545 & 0.200 \\ \hline
    
    \multirow{5}{*}{50} & \rowcolor{yellow} metis & 2.93 ms & -488 & 676 & 0.286 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} kernighan-lin & 2.65 ms & -480 & 669 & 0.286 \\
     & \rowcolor{yellow} girvan-newman & 3.15 s & -424 & 604 & 0.273 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#0 & 45.00 ns & -400 & 592 & 0.266 \\
     & \rowcolor{pink} SNN \#1 & 45.00 ns & -444 & 611 & 0.282 \\ \hline 

\end{tabular}
\caption{Results from simulations.}
\label{tab:results}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You write, "... using longtable ... ends up causing other issues". What might these issues be. Incidentally, a `tabular` environment, by construction, cannot span more than one page.

Comment: The example shown here is wrapped in a `table` environment.  Regardless of what's inside it, a `table`, which is a float, will *never* break to more than one page.  By definition, any float *must* be contained on a single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `tabular` environment cannot span more than a page, I suggest you do try using a `longtable`.

I don't think it's a good idea ot use `\multirow` since the numbers regularly end up in the blue zone, where they're difficult to spot (and read).

I'd also load the `booktabs` package and use `\addlinespace` instead of `\hline` to create offsets between the groups of rows.

Last but not least, consider aligning the numbers in the three final columns on their (implicit or explicit) decimal markers to make them easier to read.

[image]

A final remark: I can't say that I understand the gaudy color scheme. Are your readers supposed to know what the colors mean?

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{longtable,siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ ll c 
    S[table-format=-2.0] 
    S[table-format= 3.0] 
    S[table-format=-1.5,group-digits=false]} 

% headers and footers

    \caption{Results from simulations.} \label{tab:results} \\
    \toprule
    \# Nodes & Partition Type & Time & {Cut} & {Energy} & {Modularity} \\[0.25ex] 
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{Table \thetable, continued} \\[1ex]
    \toprule
    \# Nodes & Partition Type & Time & {Cut} & {Energy} & {Modularity} \\[0.25ex] 
    \hline
    \endhead
    
    \multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(continued on following page)} \\
    \endfoot
    
    \hline
    \endlastfoot


% body of table

     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{9} 
                       & kernighan-lin & 473.26 \textmu s & -11 & 17 & 0.170 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman  & 2.01 ms & -7 & 20 & 0.180 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 46.04 ms & -11 & 19 & 0.186 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 46.04 ms & -7 & 20 & 0.180 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 46.04 ms & -11 & 19 & 0.186 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 1.46 ns & -7 & 15 & 0.125 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 1.46 ns & -11 & 16 & 0.186 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 1.46 ns & -11 & 17 & 0.170 \\  
     \addlinespace   
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{18} 
                       & kernighan-lin & 715.02 \textmu s & -60 & 83 & 0.284 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 29.86 ms & -64 & 89 & 0.306 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 72.48 s & -64 & 89 & 0.305 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 72.48 s & 32 & 101 & 0.149 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 72.48 s & -64 & 89 & 0.305 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 5.83 ns & -32 & 67 & 0.245 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 5.83 ns & -32 & 73 & 0.183 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 5.83 ns & -36 & 73 & 0.208 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#3 & 5.83 ns & -44 & 74 & 0.247 \\ 
     \addlinespace  
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{20} 
                       & kernighan-lin & 979.42 \textmu s & -74 & 85 & 0.203 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 44.43 ms & -82 & 85 & 0.224 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 7.20 ns & -42 & 67 & 0.170 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 7.20 ns & -46 & 70 & 0.160 \\ 
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 7.20 ns & -58 & 74 & 0.184 \\ 
     \addlinespace    
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{22} 
                       & metis & 1.64 ms & -92 & 91 & 0.177 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & kernighan-lin & 1.61 ms & -92 & 89 & 0.177 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 84.34 ms & 180 & 101 & -0.00296 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 2.09 ks & -92 & 93 & 0.178 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 2.09 ks & -36 & 101 & 0.124 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 2.09 ks & -92 & 93 & 0.178 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 8.71 ns & -76 & 81 & 0.152 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 8.71 ns & -76 & 81 & 0.152 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 8.71 ns & -88 & 88 & 0.169 \\ 
     \addlinespace
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{24}
                       & kernighan-lin & 1.32 ms & -104 & 108 & 0.173 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 156.77 ms & -104 & 104 & 0.178 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 8.58 ks & -108 & 108 & 0.18 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 8.58 ks & -44 & 126 & 0.133 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 8.58 ks & -108 & 108 & 0.18 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 10.37 ns & -96 & 100 & 0.166 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 10.37 ns & -96 & 100 & 0.166 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 10.37 ns & -100 & 103 & 0.172 \\ 
     
     %\addlinespace
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{24} 
                       & metis & 1.36 ms  & -120 & 153 & 0.306  \\* % no page break at this line
     \rowcolor{yellow} & kernighan-lin & 15.03 ms & -120 & 153 & 0.306 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 113.37 ms & -104 & 142 & 0.272  \\ 
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 11.05 ks & -120 & 150 & 0.306  \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 11.05 ks & 76 & 178 & 0.125  \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 11.05 ks & -120 & 150 & 0.306  \\ 
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 1.44 ns & -84 & 160 & 0.234 \\ 
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 1.44 ns & -104 & 163 & 0.287  \\ 
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 1.44 ns & -116 & 157 & 0.3  \\ 
     \addlinespace 
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{25}
                       & kernighan-lin & 56.65 ms & -131 & 121 & 0.202 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 547.38 ms & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal cut & 19.97 ks & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal energy & 19.97 ks & -59 & 138 & 0.147 \\
     \rowcolor{cyan} & ideal modularity & 19.97 ks & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 11.25 ns & -103 & 106 & 0.177 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#3 & 11.25 ns &  -87 & 103 & 0.155 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#4 & 11.25 ns & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\ 
     \addlinespace 
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{35} 
                       & kernighan-lin & 1.66 ms & -233 & 324 & 0.294 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 584.88 ms & -185 & 364 & 0.274 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 22.05 ns & -157 & 269 & 0.269 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 22.05 ns &  -93 & 251 & 0.218 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 22.05 ns & -117 & 252 & 0.255 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#3 & 22.05 ns & -105 & 250 & 0.241 \\ 
     \addlinespace
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{50}
                       & kernighan-lin & 2.02 ms & -356 & 770 & 0.348 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 776.80 ms & -8 & 556 & 0.269 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 45.00 ns &  92 & 522 & 0.240 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 45.00 ns & 108 & 520 & 0.225 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#2 & 45.00 ns &  68 & 545 & 0.200 \\ 
     \addlinespace
     \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{50} 
                       & metis & 2.93 ms & -488 & 676 & 0.286 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & kernighan-lin & 2.65 ms & -480 & 669 & 0.286 \\
     \rowcolor{yellow} & girvan-newman & 3.15 s  & -424 & 604 & 0.273 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#0 & 45.00 ns & -400 &  592 & 0.266 \\
     \rowcolor{pink} & SNN \#1 & 45.00 ns & -444 &  611 & 0.282 \\ 

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The colors were chosen arbitrarily and are used to distinguish between different groups of partition types (traditional, ideal, neurotrophic). This is explained in my paper but if you have suggestions of way to make this more clear in the table I'd love some suggestions even if it is just a different coloring scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Long table should not be inserted in `table` float. It prevent table  breaking over several pages.

A wee bit changed table design (column "Time" is replaced by two columns: `S` and `s`, used is `tabularray` package with `booktabs` and `siunitx` libraries (which load packages of the same names), table rows are terminated by`\\*` with exception, where break table between pages is allowed:

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
 \SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\sffamily\itshape}
\NewColumnType{u}[1][]{Q[si={#1},l,cmd=\TblrUnit]}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Results from simulations.}, 
  label = {tab:results}
                ]{colspec = {l l
                             Q[si={table-format= 3.2{\,},
                               table-number-alignment=right}] @{} 
                              u % <---  for typing units, left aligned
                              S[table-format=-2.0]
                              S[table-format= 3.0]
                              S[table-format=-1.5,group-digits=false]
                            },
                  cell{2-Z}{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                  row{1}  = {guard},
                  rowsep = 0.25pt,
                  rowhead = 1,
                  }
% table body
\toprule
\# Nodes    
    & Partition Type    
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Time    
            &   & Cut   
                    & Energy    
                        & Modularity            \\ 
\midrule
% body of table
    \SetRow{bg=yellow} 
9   & kernighan-lin     & 473.26 & \micro\second &  -11 &  17 & 0.170 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     &   2.01 & \milli\second &   -7 &  20 & 0.180 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan} 
    & ideal cut         &  46.04 & \milli\second &  -11 &  19 & 0.186 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan} 
    & ideal energy      &  46.04 & \milli\second &   -7 &  20 & 0.180 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal modularity  &  46.04 & \milli\second &  -11 &  19 & 0.186 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &   1.46 & \nano\second  &   -7 &  15 & 0.125 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &   1.46 & \nano\second  &  -11 &  16 & 0.186 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &   1.46 & \nano\second  &  -11 &  17 & 0.170 \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
18  & kernighan-lin     & 715.02 & \micro\second &  -60 &  83 & 0.284 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     &  29.86 & \milli\second &  -64 &  89 & 0.306 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal cut         &  72.48 & \second       &  -64 &  89 & 0.305 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal energy      &  72.48 & \second       &   32 & 101 & 0.149 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal modularity  &  72.48 & \second       &  -64 &  89 & 0.305 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &   5.83 & \nano\second  &  -32 &  67 & 0.245 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &   5.83 & \nano\second  &  -32 &  73 & 0.183 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &   5.83 & \nano\second  &  -36 &  73 & 0.208 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#3           &   5.83 & \nano\second  &  -44 &  74 & 0.247 \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow} \
20  & kernighan-lin     & 979.42 & \second       &  -74 &  85 & 0.203 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     &  44.43 & \milli\second &  -82 &  85 & 0.224 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &   7.20 & \nano\second  &  -42 &  67 & 0.170 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &   7.20 & \nano\second  &  -46 &  70 & 0.160 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &   7.20 & \nano\second  &  -58 &  74 & 0.184 \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
22  & metis             &   1.64 & \milli\second &  -92 &  91 & 0.177 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & kernighan-lin     &   1.61 & \milli\second &  -92 &  89 & 0.177 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     &  84.34 & \milli\second &  180 & 101 & -0.00296 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal cut         &   2.09 & \kilo\second  &  -92 &  93 & 0.178 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal energy      &   2.09 & \kilo\second  &  -36 & 101 & 0.124 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal modularity  &   2.09 & \kilo\second  &  -92 &  93 & 0.178 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &   8.71 & \nano\second  &  -76 &  81 & 0.152 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &   8.71 & \nano\second  &  -76 &  81 & 0.152 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &   8.71 & \nano\second  &  -88 &  88 & 0.169 \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
24 & kernighan-lin      &   1.32 & \milli\second & -104 & 108 & 0.173 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     & 156.77 & \milli\second & -104 & 104 & 0.178 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal cut         &   8.58 & \kilo\second  & -108 & 108 &  0.18 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal energy      &   8.58 & \kilo\second  &  -44 & 126 & 0.133 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal modularity  &   8.58 & \kilo\second  & -108 & 108 &  0.18 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &  10.37 & \nano\second  &  -96 & 100 & 0.166 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &  10.37 & \nano\second  &  -96 & 100 & 0.166 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &  10.37 & \nano\second  & -100 & 103 & 0.172 \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
24  & metis             &   1.36 & \milli\second & -120 & 153 & 0.306  \\* 
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & kernighan-lin     &  15.03 & \milli\second & -120 & 153 & 0.306  \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     & 113.37 & \milli\second & -104 & 142 & 0.272  \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal cut         &  11.05 & \kilo\second  & -120 & 150 & 0.306  \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal energy      &  11.05 & \kilo\second  &   76 & 178 & 0.125  \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal modularity  &  11.05 & \kilo\second  & -120 & 150 & 0.306  \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &   1.44 & \nano\second  &  -84 & 160 & 0.234 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &   1.44 & \nano\second  & -104 & 163 & 0.287 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &   1.44 & \nano\second  & -116 & 157 & 0.3  \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
25  & kernighan-lin     &  56.65 & \milli\second & -131 & 121 & 0.202 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     & 547.38 & \milli\second & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal cut         &  19.97 & \kilo\second  & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal energy      &  19.97 & \kilo\second  &  -59 & 138 & 0.147 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=cyan}
    & ideal modularity  &  19.97 & \kilo\second  & -135 & 120 & 0.209 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &  11.25 & \nano\second  & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &  11.25 & \nano\second  & -103 & 106 & 0.177 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &  11.25 & \nano\second  & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#3           &  11.25 & \nano\second  &  -87 & 103 & 0.155 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#4           &  11.25 & \nano\second  & -107 & 106 & 0.184 \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
35  & kernighan-lin     &   1.66 & \milli\second & -233 & 324 & 0.294 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     & 584.88 & \milli\second & -185 & 364 & 0.274 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &  22.05 & \nano\second  & -157 & 269 & 0.269 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &  22.05 & \nano\second  &  -93 & 251 & 0.218 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &  22.05 & \nano\second  & -117 & 252 & 0.255 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#3           &  22.05 & \nano\second  & -105 & 250 & 0.241 \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
50  & kernighan-lin     &   2.02 & \milli\second & -356 & 770 & 0.348 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     & 776.80 & \milli\second &   -8 & 556 & 0.269 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &  45.00 & \nano\second  &  92 & 522 & 0.240 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           &  45.00 & \nano\second  & 108 & 520 & 0.225 \\*
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#2           &  45.00 & \nano\second  &  68 & 545 & 0.200 \\
\midrule[3pt, fg=white]
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
50 & metis              &   2.93 & \milli\second & -488 & 676 & 0.286 \\
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & kernighan-lin     &   2.65 & \milli\second & -480 & 669 & 0.286 \\
    \SetRow{bg=yellow}
    & girvan-newman     &   3.15 & \second       & -424 & 604 & 0.273 \\
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#0           &  45.00 & \nano\second  & -400 & 592 & 0.266 \\
    \SetRow{bg=pink}
    & SNN \#1           & 45.00 & \nano\second   & -444 & 611 & 0.282 \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]